# Como fica esse join corretamente?

Tags: banco-de-dados, microsoft-access

Tenho pesquisado muito como fica esse join e não estou conseguindo arrumar:

```sql
SELECT tbEquipamento.TIPO_EQUIPAMENTO, tbEquipamento.NUMERO_SERIE, tbEquipamento.COD_SITUACAO_FK, tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO, tbSituacao_Equipamento.SITUACAO
FROM tbEquipamento, tbSituacao_Equipamento
INNER JOIN tbEquipamento_Movimentacao 
ON tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO = tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK
INNER JOIN tbEquipamento
ON tbSituacao_Equipamento.COD_SITUACAO = tbEquipamento.COD_SITUACAO_FK
WHERE (((tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO_FK)= [rlMovimentacaoEquipamentoSalvo]![txtNumeroTermo]));
```

Oq estou tentando fazer é que esse join:

```sql
SELECT tbEquipamento.TIPO_EQUIPAMENTO, tbEquipamento.NUMERO_SERIE, tbEquipamento.COD_SITUACAO_FK, tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO
FROM tbEquipamento
INNER JOIN tbEquipamento_Movimentacao 
ON tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO = tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK
WHERE (((tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO_FK)= [rlMovimentacaoEquipamentoSalvo]![txtNumeroTermo]));
```

(Que esta funcionando)

Mostre a Situação do equipamento, e não o código da situação dele.

As relações entre as tabelas são:

```
tbEquipamento:
  -NUMERO_ATIVO (Primary Key)
  -TIPO_EQUIPAMENTO
  -NUMERO_SERIE
  -COD_SITUACAO_FK (Foreing Key)

tbSituacao_Equipamento:
  -COD_SITUACAO (Primary Key)
  -SITUACAO

tbEquipamento_Movimentacao: (Entidade fraca)
  -NUMERO_ATIVO_FK (Foreing Key)
  -COD_MOVIMENTACAO_FK(Foreing Key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere a coluna `COD_SITUACAO_FK` para `SITUACAO`:

```
SELECT tbEquipamento.TIPO_EQUIPAMENTO,
       tbEquipamento.NUMERO_SERIE,
       tbSituacao_Equipamento.SITUACAO,
       tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO
  FROM ((tbEquipamento
 INNER JOIN tbSituacao_Equipamento ON tbSituacao_Equipamento.COD_SITUACAO = tbEquipamento.COD_SITUACAO_FK)
 INNER JOIN tbEquipamento_Movimentacao ON tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO = tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK)
 WHERE (((tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO_FK)= [rlMovimentacaoEquipamentoSalvo]![txtNumeroTermo]));
```

Comment: Olá Sorack, obrigado pela ajuda. Esse select não funcionou. 
Acredito que seja pq a situação está em outra tabela, e não na tabela equipamento.

Comment: tbSituacao_Equipamento

Comment: Também não funcionou, isso pq a "tbEquipamento_Movimentacao" não tem a FK da "tbSituacao_Equipamento"

Comment: Boa, agora ele funcionou. Porém está mostrando todos os Equipamentos, mesmo utilizando a clausula "WHERE (((tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO_FK)=[rlMovimentacaoEquipamentoSalvo]![txtNumeroTermo]));"

Comment: E como ficaria ?

Comment: Deu um erro: Erro de sintaxe (operador faltando) na expressão de consulta 'tbSituacao_Equipamento.COD_SITUACAO = tbEquipamento.COD_SITUACAO_FK [...]"

Comment: @Saraiva veja agora

Comment: Boa, agora foi... Muito obrigado @Sorack

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem?
Um dos primeiros detalhes que eu percebi é que você estava indicando **duas tabelas** no **select** e você repetia uma delas no **INNER JOIN**.
Creio que seja melhor manter apenas uma das tabelas no select e fazer o resto utilizando o **INNER JOIN**.
Fiz algumas correções, talvez resolva o seu problema. Porém seria ótimo você disponibilizar como é o **diagrama relacional** das suas tabelas para sabermos como te ajudar melhor.

Segue as correções:

```
SELECT tbEquipamento.TIPO_EQUIPAMENTO, tbEquipamento.NUMERO_SERIE, tbEquipamento.COD_SITUACAO_FK, tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO, tbSituacao_Equipamento.SITUACAO 
FROM tbSituacao_Equipamento
INNER JOIN tbEquipamento ON tbEquipamento.COD_SITUACAO_FK = tbSituacao_Equipamento.COD_SITUACAO
INNER JOIN tbEquipamento_Movimentacao ON tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.NUMERO_ATIVO_FK = tbEquipamento.NUMERO_ATIVO 
WHERE (((tbEquipamento_Movimentacao.COD_MOVIMENTACAO_FK)= [rlMovimentacaoEquipamentoSalvo]![txtNumeroTermo]));
```

Caso a dúvida não for resolvida, estou a disposição para continuar te ajudando.

Comment: Tudo sim, Luis. Obrigado pela ajuda, mas esse select deu um "erro de sintaxe" no access

Comment: Poderia indicar o erro de sintaxe?
Como não tenho acesso ao seu banco, fica complicado fazer essas correções

Comment: Mostrar "erro de sintaxe. Operador faltando na consulta"